# ASP.NET with EF, how to autocomplete for text field to lookup from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm not even sure how to search for this - I'm using .NET MVC 4 with EF and I have 2 simple models with a one to many relationship - Company and Location.  A company can have many locations (Eg, Australia, US, Canada etc)

I'd like to create a form which has a text field where a user can enter in a comma seperated list of locations, which would either autocopmlete for existing locations, or add a new location for new ones.

Ie, if they start typing in "Aus" and Austrlia and Austria are both in the Locations database table, then the user should be shown these to choose from - exactly like StackOverflow does for Tags.  But if they type in a location that doesn't already exist in the database table then this should create a new record.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Robbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would read all locations from the DB prior to rendering the view and serialize them in a JSON structure, or a simple JavaScript array in the rendered view. This would be used for the autocomplete on the client side with the help of jQuery (you could use a plugin, but should be simple enough to make just what you need. I wouldn't complicate things by employing some kind of Ajax call to the server triggered by keydown event.

After the form is submitted, obviously the content of the location field is going to be just text. So, you'd need to look up that location in the database and if it returns nothing, you'd need to add it prior to saving the company record.

I don't know your exact model, but the code could look something like this:

```
var location = db.Locations.Find(l => l.LocationName == valueThatWasSubmitted);
if (location == null) 
{
    // save new location
} 
// location exists, proceed with the rest (saving the company, etc.)
```

Comment: I think that makes sense - how do I check if the location is new, and then save it to that record if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: You simply need to look it up in the database by the location name using a Linq query, since you're using EF. I updated the answer with an example.